# Is it possible to extend the WantedBy systemd unit property?

Tags: linux, systemd, systemctl

I have a unit file and I want to modify some of the properties. I've been able to extend all the properties using the `/etc/systemd/system/unitname.service.d/` directory but cannot get the `WantedBy` property to be extended.

**Original Unit File (deluged.service)**

```
[Unit]
Description=Deluge Bittorrent Client Daemon
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=media
Group=media
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/deluged -d -u 0.0.0.0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**/etc/systemd/system/deluged.service.d/override.conf**

```
[Unit]
BindTo=sys-subsystem-net-devices-tun0.device
After=sys-subsystem-net-devices-tun0.device

[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/deluged -d -i 10.10.10.1 -u 0.0.0.0

[Install]
WantedBy=
WantedBy=sys-subsystem-net-devices-tun0.device
```

Everything appears to work correctly except for `WantedBy` when I run `systemctl enable deluged` it still created the symlink in `multi-user` and no link is created in the new location.

I've searched for documentation on extending/overriding and I haven't seen anything talking about `WantedBy` so I have no idea if it's even possible to extend it. Am I doing something wrong or is it just not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Older systemd releases [don't support](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/1774) overriding the `[Install]` section with drop-in files. With those you need to create a [replacement file](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Replacement_unit_files) for this service, instead.

Similarly, the `Conflicts=` key in the `[Unit]` section [can't be overridden](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2017-June/038976.html) in a drop-in file, either.

---

Systemd removed that limitation in [the end of 2017](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/7278), thus, versions released after that aren't affected.

Comment: As pointed out by the other answer, it is supported since systemd 236: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/7278

Comment: @JanTojnar thanks for the link, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently using Systemd 237 and it seems take into account [install] section overrides.

At least links are created according to my drop-in file.

**/usr/lib/systemd/user/syncthing.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Syncthing - Open Source Continuous File Synchronization
Documentation=man:syncthing(1)

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/syncthing -no-browser -no-restart -logflags=0
Restart=on-failure
SuccessExitStatus=3 4
RestartForceExitStatus=3 4

# Hardening
SystemCallArchitectures=native
MemoryDenyWriteExecute=true
NoNewPrivileges=true

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

**/home/abe/.config/systemd/user/syncthing.service.d/override.conf**

```
[Install]
WantedBy=
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

systemctl --user enable syncthing.service

```
Created symlink /home/abe/.config/systemd/user/multi-user.target.wants/syncthing.service → /usr/lib/systemd/user/syncthing.service.
```